# Axioms for Non Duality

Tags: spinoza, axiom

I am interested in teachings about non-duality and I was wondering whether there are any texts that build up assertions of non-duality from a set of axioms. I am aware of Spinoza's ethics and already started reading it. But are there any other works on this topic?

Comment: [Ellam Ondre](https://ropeandsnake.files.wordpress.com/2020/04/ellam-ondre-all-is-one.pdf) and
[Ribhu Gita](https://www.amazon.com/Ribhu-Gita-Translation-Original-Sivarahasya/dp/0970366744)
 and [I am That](https://www.amazon.com/That-Talks-Sri-Nisargadatta-Maharaj/dp/8185300534).
More generally the writings/compositions of Ramana Maharshi.
[Vivek Chudamani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivekac%C5%AB%E1%B8%8D%C4%81ma%E1%B9%87i) is an ancient classic

Comment: Nondualist philosophies strictly speaking originate with and are mainly expounded by Indian traditions, the principle tradition being Advaita Vedanta, which is nowadays well-known in the West. Subsequent to its dissemination in the West, it is possible to kind of retrospectively search for examples in Western philosophy, such as Spinoza, but up until recently you would never have heard the adjective 'non-dualist' applied to Spinoza. Do some searches for "Nondualism AND (insert search tem)" and you might find some examples.

Comment: @Wayfarer Yeah I don't believe *Non Duality* was a thing in the English speaking world until someone started literal translation of *advaita* and asserting that the claims of advaita were significantly different from monism. Some of my older answers on [Ramana Maharshi](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A37256+ramana) may be of interest — a teacher generally regarded as the paragon of advaita in recent Indian context

Comment: @Rushi Thanks for your comments. I will read some of that literature.

Comment: @Wayfarer Thanks you for your comment. I will take your advice into account.

Comment: You could try "Nonduality" by David Loy. He has several great books that I refer back to.

Comment: @ScottRowe Yes I also just came across his book. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct example, maybe, but look into [positive set theory](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Positive_set_theory), where the axiomatic function that generates sets from general descriptions is restricted to *positive* descriptions, i.e. non-negative ones. Just as such, the system is still consistent with a background logic with substantive negation propositions, but so see also about e.g. [negation-free paraconsistent logic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.00357.pdf) for non-dualistic options in that direction, too.

**Justification of references:** I am assuming, for the sake of the OP question, that a "rigorous" axiomatization of non-duality would mean effacing most or all of the dichotomies that lead to substantive negation. On its face, of course, non-duality still uses the prefix "non-" in the expression of the standpoint itself, so a complete absence of negation seems impossible. (Even when, in classical logic, we find a way to collapse all the connectives, including the negation one, to the [Sheffer stroke](https://iep.utm.edu/sheffers/), we still know behind-the-scenes that this connective has the effective meaning of NAND, "not and" or "not both," so negativity is not entirely dispelled.) Indeed, that very phrase "absence of negation" is self-defeating if taken naively, since an absence can be styled a sort of weak or trivial negativity, after all.

Now, consider that there is an element of arbitrariness in calling electrons *negatively charged* and positrons *positively charged*. There is another level of representation where we could switch the descriptions per particle type as long as between the two types, a symmetrical relation held. This would be a perhaps helpful way to interpret/apply non-duality: to strongly *relativize* (almost) all negations, while maintaining a form of absolute positive representation attendant upon everything in sum.

All that being said, I don't know that set theorists and logicians who favor such systems are implicitly committed to non-duality. Positive set theory does have a proper universal set instead of a universal proper class, and sometimes the absolute set is looked upon as an ultimate oneness containing all possible being. Other times, though, [absolute infinity in the theory of proper classes is adapted to the concept of absolute divine infinity](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-31644-4_7), where the divine nature is sufficiently transcendent to dualize the world apart from Itself, or more often an extremely pluralistic worldview, that of the [set-theoretic multiverse](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/set-theoretic+multiverse), has been found helpful in navigating the multitude of set theories. Attempts to weaken (if not eliminate) ontological commitments to "the" multiverse as such are variously more or less successful; still, offhand, the prevalence of mathematical and logical pluralism nowadays tends against non-duality *in abstracto* (even if the mathematical multiverse is a convenient fiction, say, it still ends up being a fiction that is separate from the range of more stable, monism-friendly facts in the physical world, such as they are).

Comment: Right, abstract Nonduality is kind of a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @ScottRowe as I was looking over the topic today, it seemed as if they emphasized having an intuitive/experiential engagement with non-duality. Although perhaps axioms can be supported by intuitions, I wonder whether the OP would do better to look for axioms of monism, for monisms that are not standpoints of non-duality. But I confess the distinction between monism and non-duality somewhat escapes me for the time being...

Comment: I see Nonduality as an antidote for discursive thought. It would have to be a cure that one wants. "*I don't have a thinking problem, I can stop any time*"

Comment: @KristianBerry I must admit that I am overwhelmed by your answer. I don't think I have the expertise to understand the meaning of what all you wrote in your answer. Nevertheless I think I want to be able to formulate or understand a formulation of such rigor. But I will need to self-study a lot. May I send you a PM and ask you for literature I could read to get started?

Comment: @eeqesri IDK if they have a PM function here but I think my Facebook account is linked through my SE profile (I sign in on the SE via FB at any rate). To my knowledge, positive set theory originated with a certain Olivier Esser, but if he has written a book about it, I don't know it, I know his theory second-hand (my answer has a link but see also [the SEP article section on the topic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#SystGPKiOlivEsse)).